# Data not passed when using HttpResponseRedirect in DJANGO

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse

i am using Django redirect , currently it is redirecting to the page , but am not able to pass the data from views --> template .

i tried different methods checking youtube and stackoverflow questions but nothing worked , below is my code

```
def Dashboard(request):
            status = output['status']
            if(status == 'success'):
                msg = output['id']
            else:
                msg = output['error']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('AllOrders', kwargs={'status':status,'msg':msg}))
```

and here is how i fetch it in template:

```
div class="col-span-12 mt-8">
                                {%  if kwargs.status == "success" %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-outline-success alert-dismissible show flex items-center mb-2" role="alert"> {{kwargs.status}}</div>
                                {% endif %}
```

and this shows me INTERNAL SERVER ERROR , but if i remove passing arguments , everything works fine , Can anyone help me in this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to send argument value from one view to another view in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250960/unable-to-send-argument-value-from-one-view-to-another-view-in-django)

Comment: but i want to send from view to template @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: You cannot redirect with data, which is what you are trying. Anyway the answer to that question shows how you can use GET parameters or the session to pass data around. Similar to `request.session[key'']` in the view you can write `{{ request.session.key }}` in the template to the same effect.

Comment: but still it gives me Internal Server Error @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: request.session['status']  = output['status']     -------   {%  if request.session.status == "success" %}     @AbdulAzizBarkat

Answer (score 0):

Whene you pass any argument using reverse function this means you have reserved the place of that argument for example :
path('detail_int:pk)
so you can pass pk to this url as an argument
for your problem maybe you should look at the urls.py

Comment: So if it can solve my problem , what edit should i do in urls.py

Comment: The path named "AllOrders" should get arguments for example path('AllOrders_<int:status>_<iint:msg>', view(), name='AllOrders')